# how to get array based on click

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like below. What I'm trying to do is if user clicks on one of the divs and retrieving the array by combining the variables first part (standard) with whatever the index is but I can't seem to make that happen ( its after $.each(...

```
<div class="selections">
   <div id="select1"></div>
   <div id="select2"></div>
   <div id="select3"></div>
   <div id="select4"></div>
   <div id="select5"></div>
</div>

$('.selections div').on('click', function (index) {
    var numbered = $(this).index() + 1;
    var selectedSelect = $('#select' + numbered);
    $.each((standard + numbered), function (index, value) {
        if (index == numbered) {
            //code
        }
    })
    $('#select' + numbered).addClass("selectionBoxActive");
})

var standard1 = [
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "AA" }
];
var standard2 = [
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "BB" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "BB" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "BB" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "BB" }
];
var standard3 = [
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "CC" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "CC" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "CC" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "CC" }
];
var standard4 = [
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "DD" }
];
var standard5 = [
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "EE" }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe is possible to do what you are attempting with your arrays.  I would suggest transforming them into a multi-dimensional array.

```js
$('.selections div').on('click', function (index) {
    var numbered = $(this).index();
    var selectedSelect = $('#select' + numbered);
    $.each(arr[numbered], function (index, value) {
        if (index == numbered) {
            //code
            console.log(arr[numbered][index]);
        }
    })
    $('#select' + (numbered+1)).addClass("selectionBoxActive");
})
var arr = [[
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "AA" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "AA" }
],[
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "BB" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "BB" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "BB" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "BB" }
],[
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "CC" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "CC" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "CC" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "CC" }
],[
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "DD" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "DD" }
],[
    { text: "Expertise 1", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 2", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 3", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 4", abbreviation: "EE" },
    { text: "Expertise 5", abbreviation: "EE" }
]];
```

```css
.selectionBoxActive{
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selections">
   <div id="select1">1</div>
   <div id="select2">2</div>
   <div id="select3">3</div>
   <div id="select4">4</div>
   <div id="select5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that, I was just curious